# Achieving continuous code blocks in Dokuwiki

Tags: html, wiki, dokuwiki

I am aware that one can display code blocks with `<code></code>` or `<file></file>`. This usually works quite well. Unfortunately I was trying to paste a nginx configuration file and these directives break the code randomly into different blocks.
Is there no way to display the entire config file in one block?

Comment: Realized that the invisible part of your question is exactly the `<code>` block, which does not show up in the view now. I cannot fix it without change some more text which I do not want (at least 6 chars I have to change to have a revision). Could you fix that to have the question clear? I do not have any idea why that do not wok with your code anyway. It should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the whole code inside `<code>...</code>` block.

Note that you can use syntax coloring also, to give the code language also,
like `<code perl>`, a lot of languages are supported, but I'm not sure what to use for that config file. You may give a try to use for example `ini`, to have quotes colored at least. Here is the list of supported languages: http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

Answer (score 0):

Correct, I was talking about the CODE and FILE block. But I have found the mistake. The beginning of the CODE block must be indented. Then it works as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure why it must be indented for you, at least with `<code>`, indentation is an other way to mark a block as code. But with `<code>` I used many times without any indentation. But if it works for you now, then you are happy, and this is the important point.

Comment: I have to correct myself. The ```<code></code>``` block is not working properly as it tears the code apart into different block. The only way that I am able to achieve the pasting of code is to put it into a ```<nowiki></nowiki>``` block